# Como creo varias carpetas en un mismo repositorio?

Tags: github

Me explico yo creo un repositorio en github llamado proyecto, como hago para meter 3 repositorio distinto dentro, mi proyecto lleva un servidor Rest, una app android y un Swing. Mi idea es tener el repositorio del proyectoy poder tenerlo todo ahi para asi dar un solo link y no 3.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que en cada carpeta meta el repositorio de cada parte del proyecto pero cuando le doy a subir desde el tortoise no me deja.
este es el error

```
 git.exe push --progress "origin" master
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/carlos033/Proyecto/tree/main/APP/' not found


git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128) (954 ms @ 15/01/2021 16:56:43)
```

Comment: No es lo más optimo, sin embargo, si necesitas hacer eso, solo debes agregar los proyectos a la misma carpeta donde tengas tu repositorio, tendrás que hacer un git add en el directorio raíz de los 3 proyectos.

Comment: No se mezclaran los archivos?a ver en mc asao es que mi proyecto incluye esas 3 cosas y de cara a mostrarlo es ams comodo un link que 3

Comment: @unknow En términos sencillos, Git copia el estado de una carpata/directorio y sus miembros (archivos y subcarpetas/subdirectorios). Al final, la estructura y sus datos se guardará de forma íntegra en el repositorio (a menos que hagas una modificación en la configuración de dicho repositorio, como agregar o modificar un .gitignore, por ejemplo). En todo caso, una solución que permite tener en un mismo repositorio la posibilidad de llamar a varios "sub-repositorios", es el uso de [submódulos](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). Debes agregarlos al registro usando `git add`.

Comment: @unknow En concreto, qué error o mensaje te está apareciendo al intentar almacenar los cambios?

Comment: ya lo he comentado arriba el error en la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Para compartir el enlace de la carpeta APP, por ejemplo, debes usar el directorio:
https://github.com/carlos033/Proyecto/tree/main/APP

Si TortoiseGit no te deja subir nuevas versiones, puede ser por innumerables razones. Algunos ejemplos:

- El usuario no tiene permiso para añadir contenido
- El directorio local no está actualizado a la última version
- El branch local es diferente

***Si quieres saber cual es el problema, comparte el error que te da TortoiseGit para poder ayudarte.***

Comment: La última parte de la respuesta quedaría mejor en la zona de comentarios.